# Parse.com Cloud Code Versioning, it it possible?

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, versioning, parse-cloud-code

I'm a iOS developer and I have just lunched my app to the AppStore.

I'm using Parse.com in my app. Cloud Code for the services. Heroku.com connected with my parse.com app for the Socket.

Now I need to change some functions in my app's CloudCode and in the iOS client too and resubmit the app, but I do not want the new version of the CloudCode worked with old version of the app.

I need to have a versioning on my Parse.com app's CloudCode. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your own versioning by providing a version key in the request to cloud code functions. Each cloud code function which supports multiple versions can check for this value to decide what logic should be applied. Any which don't will simply ignore the additional parameter.

Comment: Yes this is a variant, I hope there exists better variant, as in this case I should add many cases and the number of cases will increase after each version. Thanks!